The test dataloader evaluation model has an impact on the training process？
I found that after adding this code“for data in test_loader”, even if I didn't write anything in the "for loop", the value of loss calculated by the model would change.
I have set the random seed, and when I do not change the program, the loss of running the program repeatedly remains the same.My pytorch version is 1.9.0+cu111.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas.
Here's my code：
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision import datasets

batch_size = 64
learning_rate = 0.01
momentum = 0.5
EPOCH = 10
torch.manual_seed(0)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(0)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data/mnist', train=True, transform=transform,download=True)
test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data/mnist', train=False, transform=transform,download=True)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),)
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),)
        self.fc = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(320, 50),
            torch.nn.Linear(50, 10),)
    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = x.view(batch_size, -1)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x
model = Net()


criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() 
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum) 


def train(epoch):
    running_loss = 0.0
    running_total = 0
    running_correct = 0
    for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        inputs, target = data
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, target)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, dim=1)
        running_total += inputs.shape[0]
        running_correct += (predicted == target).sum().item()

    print(epoch + 1, running_loss / len(train_loader))


**def test():
    with torch.no_grad():    
        for data in test_loader:         # Whether to comment the line will happen the problem I said
            a=0
    return 0**


if __name__ == '__main__':
    acc_list_test = []
    for epoch in range(EPOCH):
        train(epoch)
        acc_test = test()



In your for epoch in loop, you are calling train, wouldn't you be expecting your model to change?

PyTorch is known to have reproducibility issues.

Sorry，maybe i didn't explain the question clearly. When I do not add for data in test_loader:, the loss value of running the program is the same every time, and the program can be repeated.   But，when i add for data in test_loader：,the loss value is different from the previous one.
